# Characters Padding in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, padding

I want to create a padding in my column that starts with 1
like 100001. I use this query however I encountered problem when it reaches 2 already.

```
select format(convert(int,totalcount), '100000') from logging
```

Data

```
1161
1164
1166
1173
100000
200015
200019
```

Query Result

```
101161
101164
101166
101173
100000
1200015
1200019
```

Expected Result

```
101161
101164
101166
101173
100000
200015
200019
```

Comment: Does this what you want ?. select 100000 + convert(int,totalcount) from logging  If not then you need to explain what does reaching 2 means, showing the original values.

Comment: This is my actual records:1108
1133
1135
1142
1160
1165
1170
199999
200001     now I want to add a padding 6 characters that starts with '1' this number is incremental. The problem is when it reaches 2xxxxx it exceeds from 6 characters already

Comment: I have no idea why you want to do this, but assuming your data is held as `int` values, you can just add on `100000` when the `totalcount` values is less than that: `select case when totalcount < 100000 then totalcount + 100000 else totalcount end`

Comment: Those records doesn't match the Actual Result and Expected Result that you have already posted. Can you edit your question and add the Actual Records, Actual Result and Expected Result for exactly the same records ?, this way we can vote to reopen the question and answer it.

Comment: select case when convert(int,totalcount) < 100000  then 100000 + convert(int,totalcount) else convert(int,totalcount) end from logging

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: Yes, it still needs another reopen vote. I have offered a solution on another comment, but do you realize that you are going to get duplicates ?. By your logic 1173 and 101173 are going to return both the same result: 101173

Answer (score 0):

You could also do the following:

```
select case when num<100000 then num+100000 else num end
from (values (1161),(1164),(1166),(1173),(100000),(200015),(200019) ) tbl(num)
```

see here: https://rextester.com/CIU94472

Sorry, I only just noticed that this is in essence the solution that @Marc Guillot already offered in his comment.